# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: mot/ajouter.html

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I am buiding adictionary and all my pages seem not to exist exept indext.html. I keep reccieving that message:TemplateDoesNotExist[here is the configuration in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlqeo.png),[here is the configuration in settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuX9M.png), [here is the configuration in views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1vyf.png)[Here is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abB0x.png), [here is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nUWa.png).
NB: I face this issue with my other pages exept index.html

I tried configuring my template files in views ans urls.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/67579). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).